# How to add System.ServiceModel to my project for good?

Tags: wcf

I'm making a helloworld game with networking for multiplayer and I got my hands on an example class that uses `MessageBuffer` and such, so I figured I should add `System.ServiceModel` to my solution.

First I tried adding it via using statement, then I found out how to add references to projects and so I did, but even after that my code has red squigglies all around saying `MessageBuffer` are not recognized.

Then I read somewhere I could try changing target framework from client to full, but that didn't help at all.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fully qualifying the name to [System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messagebuffer.aspx) to see if that helps or adding

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
```

Comment: Strangely enough, this didn't help at first, but after reloading the project several times, it did.

Comment: Still, how do I use classes without explicitly typing in every part of parent assembly?

Comment: If you exclude using System.ServiceModel.Channels you need to fully qualify the name (System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageBuffer buffer = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageBuffer()). With the using statement in place you can simply use MessageBuffer buffer = new MessageBuffer()

Comment: For some reason without explicitly typing "using System.Servicemodel.Channels" MessageBuffer will not be recognized. I thought my problem was with something else, but in the end adding ".Channels" fixed it. Feels wrong, though.

Comment: Why does it feel wrong ? MessageBuffer is in the System.ServiceModel.Channels namespace...

Comment: I'm not certain whether using <parent namespace name> provides child namespaces' classes usage, but I'm just following my simple logic.

Comment: It doesn't - namespaces have to be explicit.